# Django Query's issues

Tags: python, django

I am doing some Django practice through Coding for entrepreneurs.
This is the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

from .models import KirrURL

def kirr_redirect_view(request,shortcode=None,*args,**kwargs):

    #Method 1:

    obj = get_object_or_404(KirrURL, shortcode__iexact=shortcode)
    obj_url = obj.url

    #Method 2:

    qs = KirrURL.objects.filter(shortcode__iexact=shortcode)
    if qs.exists() and qs.count() == 1:
        obj = qs.first()
        obj_url = obj.url

    return HttpResponse("Hello : {sr}".format(sr=obj_url))
```

What I am doing is I get some words from url and pass it in to the kirr_redirect_view,and usde query to get the data and return some words.
The website introduced two methods to do it.The second works fine.When I changed to first method.The method suddenly got wrong and I kept getting 404 from the page even if I passed the correct key words.

Comment: If option 2 is recommended by a website you are using, you need to find another tutorial straight away. That does three queries for absolutely no reason at all.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Django document:

> [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):
>
> Calls **get()** on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.

Hence, if there is no matching record, `get_object_or_404` will raise `404: content not found`.

Where as in your second method, if there is no match i.e. your `if` failes, still you send your `HttResposne` object which holds the status as `200: OK` by default.

In short, your `KireURL` model has no record matching `shortcode__iexact=shortcode`.

Comment: I mean that when I input the same shortcode argument which is build definitely in my database, the first method fails, and the second worked fine.I don't know why.I think it should get the same result.Or should I give some extra code for you to check?

Answer (score 0):

Does second method showing you url or just not raising error? Filter will never raise any exception, as well as it is looking like it have more then 1 objects with same short code or dont have any and going in if condition.That's why get_object_or_404() is raising exception.

Comment: I now ran that in the shell again.I can get exact result by using get method while get_object_or_404 kept failing......

Answer (score 0):

I add some information here.This is what I got when I used python shell to run the code.

```
>>> from shortener.models import KirrURL
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
>>> obj = get_object_or_404(KirrURL,shortcode='pric3e')

Traceback (most recent call last):File"/Users/phil/Desktop/django110/lib/python3.5/site
packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 85, in get_object_or_404
return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/phil/Desktop/django110/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
shortener.models.DoesNotExist: KirrURL matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/phil/Desktop/django110/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 93, in get_object_or_404
raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
django.http.response.Http404: No KirrURL matches the given query.

>>> obj = KirrURL.objects.get(shortcode='pric3e')
>>> obj
<KirrURL: http://google.com>
>>> obj.id
1
>>> obj.url
'http://google.com'
```